# Iterator print LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I have a problem regarding the display of my LinkedList with a foreach.

When I want to display my LikedList an error comes from my list which tells me that I have to use an iterator. Here is the code:

```
public class Set {

private LinkedList <Integer> elements;

public Set () {
    this.elements = new LinkedList <Integer> ();
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Set test = new Set ();
    test.add (8);
    test.add (2);
    test.add (7);
    for (int e: test) {

    }
}
```

So I used an iterator for the display but a message tells me that my iterator is undefined for the method set.

Here is the code:

```
public class Set {

private LinkedList <Integer> elements;

public Set () {
    this.elements = new LinkedList <Integer> ();
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Set test = new Set ();
    test.add (8);
    test.add (2);
    test.add (7);
    Iterator <Integer> iterator = test.iterator ();
    while (iterator.hasNext ()) {
        System.out.println (iterator.next ());
    }
}
```

If you can help me with that, it will help me a lot.

(I tried to define "`Iterator <Integer> iterator = this.elements.iterator ();`" in the Set () public and call it in the hand that way but without success "`while (iterator.hasNext ()) {
System.out.println (iterator.next ());
}`")

Thank you in advance, nice day

Comment: There is already a `Set` interface. Please rename your class. It's confusing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have a class called Set and you use LinkedList inside, why? Why don't you use HashSet for example?

Comment: @Michael Dz, Because the use of a LinkedList was imposed on me

Comment: And you think any class that contains some collection is iterable by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Set class needs to implement iterable interface as

```
public class Set implements Iterable<Integer> {

  private LinkedList<Integer> elements;

  public Set() {
    this.elements = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return elements.iterator();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try. So to display the elements I did not make a "System.out.println (iterator (test));" in the main?

Comment: System.out.println `(iterator.next ());` will work. You can also use `test.forEach(System.out::println);` as mentioned by @Hülya. I wanted to explain the reason for  _So I used an iterator for the display but a message tells me that my iterator is undefined for the method set._

Comment: @ValentinLemains can you please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Set` doesn't define an iterator you should add for example a method like that one:

```
public Iterator<Integer> getIterator() {
     return elements.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)